# Right HTML 5 Article Structure

Tags: html, structure, article

I hope the question is not too generic, but I would need an advice:

Which one of the following examples would you consider to be the right one?

**Number 1**

```
<article>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </header>
        <p>Content</p>

        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <footer>
            <p>footer</p>
        </footer>
    </section>
</article>
```

**Number 2**

```
<article>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </header>
        <p>Content</p>

        <header>
            <h2>Title 2</h2>
        </header>
        <p>Content</p>

        <footer>
            <p>footer</p>
        </footer>
    </section>
</article>
```

**Number 3**

```
<article>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </header>
        <p>Content</p>
        <footer>
            <p>footer</p>
        </footer>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </header>
        <p>Content</p>
        <footer>
            <p>footer</p>
        </footer>
    </section>
</article>
```

I would prefer example number 1, but I am not totally sure :/

Comment: Are you looking for html or xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 are equivalent. Use whichever you prefer. The implicit section started by the `<h2>` is *inside* the explicit section.

3 is semantically different. The `<h2>` in the second section has the same ranking as `<h1>` in the first section, and the two sections are peers.

Comment: Just want to make sure: You are saying #1 and #2 are equal. Does this mean that the `header` element can be used multiple times inside one `section` (as seen in example #2)?

Comment: @Andrej - Yes it can. You can even put the footer at the start of the section and the header at the end. Or mix multiple headers and footers up in any order. The one thing you can't do is to have a header or footer inside a header or footer. So `<section><header><article>...</article></header></section>` is OK, but `<section><header><article><header>...</header></article></header></section>` is not. Incidentally, though, using `<header>` is redundant if its only content is a single `<h[1-6]>` element.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! p.s. in the real code I am using something like `<header><h1>title</h1><p>subtitle</p></header>` - forgot to add that in my examples above :)